# Использование UserControl в UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, usercontrol

Добавил свой `UserControl`, перенес туда нужный код из `Xaml` добавил юзинги. В кодбихайнд добавил нужный мне метод, но вот я не вижу теперь этих элементов при запуске приложения.

Нужно как-то дополнительно вызывать этот `UserControl`?

```
public sealed partial class ImageManipulatorControl:UserControl
{
    public ImageManipulatorControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void CollageImgage1_Manipulation(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Manipulation(e, CollageImg1);
    }


    private void Manipulation(ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e, Image image)
    {
        CompositeTransform ct = (CompositeTransform)image.RenderTransform;
        ct.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        ct.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
        ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        ct.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        ct.Rotation += Math.PI * e.Delta.Rotation;
    }
}
```

`XAML`

```
<UserControl
x:Class="PhotoRedactor.Controls.ImageManipulatorControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PhotoRedactor"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:viewModels="using:PhotoRedactor.ViewModels"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModels:EffectsViewModel x:Name="EffectsViewModel"/>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel x:Name="MainViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="GreenYellow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="2235" Height="1316" Margin="122,217,-1957,-1233">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition Width="313*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1053*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Canvas Margin="0"
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            IsTapEnabled="False"
            x:Name="CollageArea"
            IsHoldingEnabled="False"
            IsRightTapEnabled="False"
            IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            DataContext="{StaticResource EffectsViewModel}">


    </Canvas>
    <Image Width="525"
               Height="331"                  
               Canvas.Top="-388"
               Canvas.Left="-140"
               x:Name="CollageImg1"
               ManipulationMode="All"
               Source="{Binding CollageImg1}"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
               ManipulationDelta ="CollageImgage1_Manipulation"
               Visibility="{Binding IsCollageImg1Visible,
           Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
        DataContext="{StaticResource EffectsViewModel}" Margin="21,227,9.6,758">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да.

```
<Page ...>
    <Grid Background=...>
        <local:ТутИмяВашегоЮзерКонтрола />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

---

Расследование в комментариях показало следующее:

Нужно установить `DataContext` для `UserControl`'а во внешнем контейнере (в нашем случае, в `Page`), таким образом `DataContext` будет общий для внешнего окна и контрола. Затем, нужно привязываться к свойствам `DataContext` через `Binding`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43202/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd--usercontrol--uwp).

Comment: Это при том условии, что вам необходимо использовать один и тот же экземпляр класса